# Custom e-mail headers in AWS SES using Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I want to add a [`References`-header](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Gmail-decide-which-emails-go-into-which-threads) to the outgoing e-mails I send via AWS SES. I can't find anything referencing this in the [go repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go), nor the documentation.

I found this:

```
_, err := svc.SendEmailWithContext(aws.BackgroundContext(), params, func(req *request.Request) {
  req.HTTPRequest.Header.Add("References", referencesID)
})
```

But AFAIK this just tweaks the outgoing request to SES, not the message itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing using the gomail/gomail package and `SendRawMessage`:

```
svc := ses.New(awsSession)

msg := gomail.NewMessage()
msg.SetHeader("From", config.FromEmail)
msg.SetHeader("To", email)
msg.SetHeader("Subject", subject)
msg.SetHeader("References", referencesID)
msg.SetHeader("In-Reply-To", referencesID)
msg.SetBody("text/html", body)

var emailRaw bytes.Buffer
msg.WriteTo(&emailRaw)

message := &ses.RawMessage{Data: emailRaw.Bytes()}

params := &ses.SendRawEmailInput{
    RawMessage: message,
}

_, err := svc.SendRawEmail(params)
```